# Test network with DHCPDISCOVER without DHCPREQUEST

Tags: dhcp, testing

While starting a portable OS Linux, I need to test all available network interfaces with DHCPDISCOVER. Then, judging on the response DHCPOFFER, I do the choose of the correct interface and ask the DHCP server with dhclient, as it is usual. I did not find any suitable dhcp client/test/probe for this purpose. For lot of protocols there is possible to try the handshake procedure manually, as it was possible with serial modem (who remembers AT - commands). While using dhclient, it always try to finish the whole handshake procedure (continues with DHCPREQUEST/DHCPACK) even with the wrong dhcp server. Yes, it is possible to put the "reject" option in the dhclient.conf, but then the whole procedure last too long with all the necessary timeouts. 
Does anybody can show me some guide-lines how it is possible to realise such task? 
(I do write the bash scripts, and perhaps I can write some short C program, too.)

Comment: There's a reason why you can't find an easy way to do what you want: if you receive conflicting offers from different DHCP servers the network is misconfigured.

Comment: The goal is to find the "home" network, and configure the corresponding interface only. But people in our workgroup do have 1 - 4 interfaces, some connected, some not, one (do not know which) hopefully connected to our "home" net, and some may be connected to other net even the Internet. I cannot suppose nothing advance, neither the MAC, neither the name of the interface. I can rely on the disjunctive network and the addres range of my "home" net only.

Comment: As I found in the source books: the DHCP protocol is designed in more steps, so that the client can choose from the "offered" addresses (DHCPOFFER can give more than one address), but I can refuse all of them, and do not continue with the DHCPREQUEST at all.

Comment: I don't think there is any sane solution to your problem if you don't know in advance what interface is connected to your network. _shrug_